# Make a plot in Julia programming language

Tags: visualization, julia

Is there any tool in Julia to plot a figure like it can be done in MATLAB `plot(x,y)`? A brief look in manual has given me nothing.

Comment: Use PlotLy? https://plot.ly/julia/line-and-scatter/

Comment: How could I install it?

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970817/plot-not-defined-with-julia).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base Julia doesn't provide plotting functionality, that is provided by packages, e.g.

- [Gadfly.jl](http://gadflyjl.org/) - `Pkg.add("Gadfly")`
- [PyPlot.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl) - `Pkg.add("PyPlot")`, but needs Python and `matplotlib` installed.
- [Winston.jl](https://github.com/nolta/Winston.jl) - `Pkg.add("Winston")`

Comment: Today, many people also use the Plots package ecosystem: https://juliaplots.github.io/

Comment: I agree. 

@IainDunning Please add to your answer
Plots.jl - Pkg.add("Plots") - http://docs.juliaplots.org/