# Julia - ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: plot not defined

Tags: julia

Hi team Julia Community,
I shall be glad for your help with the above-stated issue. I am trying to use both the 'Gadfly' and 'PyPlot' plotting functionality in Julia, but I keep getting the above-mentioned error. I have done all I can at this point including following the instructions at - [Plot not defined with Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970817/plot-not-defined-with-julia) -, but no avail. I am using Julia version v"0.6.3" on Windows 10.

Kindly see the attached screenshots for your perusal.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help with this issue.

Comment: Did you load the package first? E.g. with `using PyPlot`? Please also copy-paste the input output instead of posting images like this.

Comment: Fred, Yes, I invoked "using PyPlot" first, but it's still not working. Will try and copy-paste next time. Anyway, I just found out that the following works: ENV["MPLBACKEND"]="tkagg"
using PyPlot