# Is there a reason why plot gives an error in atom but works fine on jupyter-notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, atom-editor, plots.jl

I am a new user of Julia. I want to start using Julia in Atom using Juno. Before I did some tutorials using jupyter-notebooks. 
Now the when I tried to run the code below it returns the following error message.
When I run the same code, on the same machine in a jupyter-notebook I do not get an error.

There are a lot of people online that get the same error but none of the solutions could help me. It seems to me that the problem that plots is not precompiling correctly.
For example: [Plot not defined with Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970817/plot-not-defined-with-julia)

```
using Plots 
x = 1:10;
y = rand(10); # These are the plotting data
plot(x,y)
```

UndefVarError: plot not defined
top-level scope at testatom.jl:3

Comment: Do you get any errors in Juno's REPL when executing that code? If so, please update your question to include those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, try rebuilding plots?

```
using Pkg;pkg”build Plots”
```

Also do any updates suggested in atom.

Also, which version of julia? Please note that link is very old...

Comment: Updating atom fixed it. Thanks a lot